# Gnuplot, change the color of data points and x-axis

Tags: colors, label, gnuplot, axis, points

I'm trying to get different points color and enter the points of second file on x-axis in the same graph.

I have two different files which contains : (y-axis:D,A,Q,F ; x-axis: 1-5 and 6-10)
1.file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEdCv.png)
2. file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8m0O.png)

Then I wrote this code to draw :

```
set style data labels
xcoord(N)= (N)
ycoord(N) = (column(0)+1)
symbol(N) = strcol(N) ne "/" ? strcol(N) : "/"
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:5]
set ytics ("D" 1, "A" 2, "Q" 3, "F" 4)
plot for [N=0:6] 'doc.txt' using (xcoord(N)):(ycoord(N)):(symbol(N)):(symbol(N)) w labels tc lt 7 font "Helvetica,12" notitle, \
for [N=0:6] 'doc1.txt' using (xcoord(N)):(ycoord(N)):(symbol(N)):(symbol(N)) w labels tc lt 1 font "Helvetica,10" notitle
```

and currently the output looks like this:
graph of 1.file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMQUB.png) graph of two data files [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vixUG.png)

As you can see, the all points are overlapping.
I want to use different colors for /, 5, g, 3 and o
and plot the points of second files in the x-axis 6-10.
How can I do that? Can someone help in correcting my commands.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question fully, but to move the points from the second file over by six units on x you could modify the plot command to be:

```
plot for [N=0:6] 'doc.txt' using (xcoord(N)):(ycoord(N)):(symbol(N)):(symbol(N)) w labels tc lt 7 font "Helvetica,12" notitle, \
     for [N=0:6] 'doc1.txt' using (6+xcoord(N)):(ycoord(N)):(symbol(N)):(symbol(N)) w labels tc lt 1 font "Helvetica,10" notitle
```

Can you clarify what color you want to use for the points?  Your sample output does use a different color for the points in each file; is that not what you wanted?

Edit

I am making up a data format because you haven not shown any actual data, but perhaps the example below is enough to get you started.

```
$DATA << EOD
3 F / / 3 g 3
2 Q / / o / 5
1 A / o / / 5
0 D / / 5 / g
EOD

set xrange [0:7]
set yrange [-1:4]
set tics nomirror
set border 3
unset key

# These are the hexadecimal RGB representations of 
#              "red"      "blue"    "yellow" "green"   "purple"
array colors = [0xFF0000, 0x0000FF, 0xFFFF00, 0x00FF00, 0xC080FF]
array symbol = ["/", "5", "g", "3", "o"]

color( sym ) = sum [i=1:5] (symbol[i] eq sym ? colors[i] : 0)

plot for [N=1:6] $DATA using (N) : (column(1)) : (strcol(N)) : (color(strcol(N))) \
                 with labels tc rgb variable font ":Bold"
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could do something with palette colors and numerical values rather than discrete RGB color names. That would be a different approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,!!! I can see the points from the second file on the x-axis. I want to use for the points, for example, / red, 5 blue, g yellow, 3 green, o purple. Is it possible to make?

Comment: I wrote more in the script: set palette defined (/ "red", 5 "blue"; g "yellow", 3"green", o"purple") ; plot for [N=0:6] 'doc.txt' using (xcoord(N)):(ycoord(N)):(symbol(N)) w labels tc lt 7 font "Helvetica,12" palette notitle . But gnuplot can't run the script. I can read the message "invalid expression". Could you help me? How can I change the color of points? Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Very kind of you. I will try again. Have a nice evening,!

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your answer. It's very very helpful.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLuoF.png

I can see now my graph, what I want to have.

Have a nice evening,! :)

Many thanks,

Chang.